# Theoretically big problem with my Tic tac toe game , but for me all seems good

Tags: c++, matrix, visual-c++, tic-tac-toe

So I went to the next step in learning c++ and that's a matrix. I tried to do an easy tic tac toe game but my game fails to correctly check if the game is over. If you put height = 2 and width = 2 in the first round it says you won... I don't see where could I have messed it up, all seemed pretty good in my mind...

```
   int map[3][3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        map[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

bool finished = false;
int player = 1;
while (!finished) {
    //attack
    cout << "player " << player << " it is your turn"<< endl;

    cout << "The map looks like this:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << map[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    bool correctMove;
    int height, width;
    do
    {
        correctMove = true;
        cout << "Where do you want to attack?" << endl;
        cout << "height = "; cin >> height;
        cout << "width = "; cin >> width;
        if (map[height][width] != 0 || width > 2 || height > 2) {
            correctMove = false;
        }
    } while (!correctMove);
    map[height][width] = player;
    //check finish game
    bool foundSequenceLine = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (map[height][i] != player) {
            foundSequenceLine = false;
        }
    }
    bool foundSequenceColumn = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (map[i][width] != player) {
            foundSequenceColumn = false;
        }
    }
    bool foundSequenceDiag1 = true;
    if (height == width) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (map[i][i] != player) {
                foundSequenceDiag1 = false;
            }
        }
    }
    bool foundSequenceDiag2 = true;
    if (height + width == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (map[2-i][i] != player) {
                foundSequenceDiag2 = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (foundSequenceColumn || foundSequenceLine || foundSequenceDiag1 || foundSequenceDiag2) {
        finished = true;
        cout << "Congrats player " << player << " you won!!!";
    }

    //change turn
    if (player == 1) {
        player++;
    }
    else {
        player--;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try to step line by line through your code with a debugger? At which line the actual behavior differs from your expectation?

Comment: @ThomasSablik that's what i'm doing right now, but i said, maybe can spot the mistake without using a break point. idk

Comment: @Victor So why should we help you, if you haven't even spent the few minutes trying to analyze the problem yourself or made sure to post an actually compiling sample?

Comment: @Voo I put the breakpoint on every line(which matter) until finish check and got no problem..

Comment: @Voo the sample compiles.  I was able to run it as posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### code makes an assumption, then avoids checking it.

Your code assumes the player has won unless you can exhaustively prove they haven't.
The problem is that you then short-circuit two of the tests that prove a move is not a winning move.

Look at what this code is doing:

```
   bool foundSequenceDiag1 = true;
    if (height == width) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (map[i][i] != player) {
                foundSequenceDiag1 = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

First, you say "the player has won" `foundSequenceDiag1=true;`.   Then you say, "was the move on a diagonal?", and only then do you run code that can set `foundSequenceDiag1` to false.

If the player makes a move that isn't on the diagonal, the check won't run.

to fix:

```
    bool foundSequenceDiag1 = (height==width);  // true if the player played on diagonal
    if (foundSequenceDiag1) {  // loop code now only executes if player played on diagonal
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (map[i][i] != player) {
                foundSequenceDiag1 = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

#### when you've found something, stop looking.

If I were writing your checks, I'd make use of the `break` keyword to stop looking once I found an answer.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (map[i][i] != player) {
            foundSequenceDiag1 = false;
            break; // can't be true now, so stop checking.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I'm gonna check immediately to see if it works. About that break; I haven't learned yet what it does. I read somewhere that it stops the loop but that's it, no condition or next steps where mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: `break` simply terminates the current loop early.  It only affects the loop that it's in: if that loop is inside an outer loop, the outer loop will keep going.